# MS-Edge on linux - without telemetry - for PDF/EPUB annotations

Tags: linux, open-source

Although I dislike M$ a lot, they do have a few impressive products.

I use Codium as a non-telemetry alternative to VS-Code. I don't know enough to know if it's actually a "safe" options, but I trust that people who know much more than me would point out any problems since it's open-source.

I would like to use a web-based e-book reader...which allows me to make annotations to e-pub & pdf files, and I understand that MS-Edge can do this.
Can anyone point me to info on how safe this would be, or an alternative that could be used or hooked in to a self-hosted e-book library system like "kavita".

I am not bound to kavita, but of the systems I have seen, it looks quite good - any suggestions welcomed.

All these ramblings aside, my questions are these...

- is there a telemetry-removed binary of MS-Edge for linux (the equivalent of codium)
- is there a web-based reader that allows annotations on PDF/EPUB?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.